# How to enter a buy trade when 3 consecutive candles close above EMA?

Tags: pine-script

I'm new to pine script and I am trying to figure out how to make a trade entry with the requirement:
**`IF (3 consecutive candles close above ema 9) THEN (enter the trade)`**.

So far, all I have is an entry signal when the EMA line crosses over the price.

```js
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

ma = ema(close, 9)

entry() => crossover(close, ma)
exit() => crossover(close, ma) 

strategy.entry(id = "long_ma", long = true, when = entry())
strategy.close(id = "long_ma", when = exit())
```

How can I use the 3 last candles for the entry?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally this is a site for helping with code problems and not writing code for complete solutions. It is also important to clearly formulate a question. What is your question?

Comment: To setup your trading entries and exits, look [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html).

Answer (score 2):

This code defines a `aboveMa` base condition that is true when `close` is > ma. From that base condition, we use the [history-referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) to refer to the same condition some bars back and then assemble those conditions to build composite conditions.

Two versions of the composite conditions are built:

- One that repaints because it uses the `close` of the realtime bar (the `aboveMa` condition in the definition of `threeAboveMa2`).
- One that doesn't repaint.

For each of these you have two conditions:

- One that is true whenever 3 consecutive bars are above the ma.
- One that is only true when the first 3 consecutive bars above the ma occur.

The markers help see where each conditions triggers. The non-repainting marker will trigger one bar later than the repainting one, but will be more reliable because all the bars it is looking at are closed bars.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Script", overlay = true)

ma = ema(close, 9)

// Base condition
aboveMa = close > ma

// No repaint
threeAboveMa = aboveMa[1] and aboveMa[2] and aboveMa[3]
first3AboveMa = not aboveMa[4] and threeAboveMa

// Repaint
threeAboveMa2 = aboveMa and aboveMa[1] and aboveMa[2]
first3AboveMa2 = not aboveMa[3] and threeAboveMa2

// Debugging
plot(ma)
plotchar(aboveMa, "aboveMa", ".", location.top)
plotchar(threeAboveMa, "threeAboveMa", "•", location.top)
plotchar(first3AboveMa, "first3AboveMa", "▲", location.top)
plotchar(first3AboveMa2, "first3AboveMa", "▼", location.top)
```

[image]

Comment: It seem that the OP want to actually make an entry/exit. So perhaps you should add that to your code?

Comment: Well, he had working entry/exit code already, so figured I'd let him assemble things himself with whichever conditions he decided he wanted to use. He seemed proficient enough to do that.